# Template conversion from XHTML 1 to HTML5 , CSS Error

Tags: javascript, css, html, xhtml-1.0-strict

This is a simple 3-column template, with Side-bars on Left and on Right sides and content in the middle. I'm not able to understand the spacing between the columns, there's too much of space between the content(post) column and right side-bar.

```
[side-bar] [content/ post / matter]_____space/gap___[side-bar]
```

I'm not able to reduce/remove the  '**_space/gap** ' to make the template look like

```
[side-bar] [content/ post / matter] [side-bar]
```

Before posting this here, I've tried chrome-developer tool to know and refactor it, I've not been able to understand it.

## <kbd>[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/srisree/xcync74h/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this section of your code:

```
#right {
float: right;
width: 180px;
padding: 10px 30px 10px 0;
}
```

to this:

```
#right {
float: left;
width: 180px;
margin-left: 10px;
padding: 10px 30px 10px 0;
}
```

Floating right will hold that container to the rightmost position it can attain within its own container.

Comment: Care to explain what's wrong about this answer that it deserves downvotes?

Comment: Hi josh, this actually worked !, I spent some 2Hrs to figure out how before posting it here ! I've accepted it as answer. Thank you,